# How to implement a FlatList inside of a Pressable without scrolling getting disabled?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Basically, I want the FlatList to have a onPress functionality (to explain simply) as well as the default scrolling functionality. Right now, if I have a FlatList inside a Pressable, then I am not able to scroll through the FlatList.

I have also tried to put Pressable inside the FlatList's RenderItem component, but I have a lot of items I'll be displaying, so it's going to inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Pressable` wrapping the `FlatList`, I learnt that we can use React Native's **Gesture Responder System** on a simple View to get the behavior that I require.

```
<View
    onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
    onResponderRelease={doSomethingFunction}
>
    <FlatList
        data={someData}
        renderItem={renderItemComponent}
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try touch handling on FlatList item parent container like below so the scrolling issue would never come again and you can easily handle the touch on each item separately

```
<FlatList
  style={{...}}
  data={[...]}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {...}}>
      <View>
        ....
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: I have specified above that I will have numerous items that are going to be rendered. Even if I use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` inside `RenderItem`, it is still going to get rendered for every item in the list, which goes to around 500 in my case. 

I will rephrase my question to be clearer. Is there a way to have a function be called whenever a user taps _anywhere_ inside the `FlatList`, while still having the scrolling capability?

Comment: @KingDoge What are you trying to achieve? `onPress` should implement on list 
 of item's parent container only so that way you can identify which item get pressed by having it's index and item itself. One more suggestion, if you have 500 items then you can use pagination in `flatlist` and display 10 to 20 items in the first place then more items on request need.

Comment: I don't want identify which item got pressed. Thanks for the suggestion about Pagination, it might help with some other problems. But like I said in my question and my previous comment. I just want to run a function if a user taps anywhere inside my `FlatList` component.